# apache error: cannot fork() for upload-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: apache, cgi

На сервере Fedora 29 в LXC контейнере, к Apache/2.4.38 прикручен git-core, конфиг рабочий, взят с другого сервера. 
При выполнении fork в CGI скриптах возникает ошибка

**`error: cannot fork() for upload-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable`**

Ошибку получить удалось из скрипта bash прокладки, который уже вызывал git-http-backend и перенаправлял stderr в файл.

`exec /var/www/..../cgi/git-http-backend $@ 2>/var/www/..../cgi_err.log`

Если предварительно установить environment то git-http-backend выполняется нормально и отдаёт то что должен, т.е. ресурсов на самом сервере достаточно.

Ошибка fork()-а возникает только под apachе-ем.

Пробовал устанавливать в конфиге различные лимиты, не помогло.

Какие могут быть мысли, в какую сторону копать?

UPD: из скрипта выполнил ulimit -a

`core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15659
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 150
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 1048576
file locks                      (-x) unlimited`

Answer (score 0):

Лечение: в конфиге модуля Apache mpm надо раскомментировать загрузку модуля mod_mpm_prefork.so и закомментировать загрузку модуля mod_mpm_event.so